# How do I divide so I get a decimal value?

Tags: java, math, division, modulus

I want to know how to get remainder and quotient in single value in Java.

Example:

> 3/2 I should get value as 1.5.

If I use the `/` operator I get only the quotient. If I user the `%` operator I get only the remainder. How do I get both at a time in the same variable?

Answer (score 57):

```
quotient = 3 / 2;
remainder = 3 % 2;

// now you have them both
```

Comment: @endless: True, you'd have to convert to integer first.  And you'd also have to specify what you mean by remainder of two floats, since it's usually defined in terms of integer arithmetic.

Comment: Just if somebody goes over this question and wonders how you would get not the quotient, but the largest natural number <= the quotient or the mod you can use the function in the math package: `Math.floorDiv(x,y)` and `Math.floorMod(x,y)`

Comment: perfect and simple. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

In your example, Java is performing *integer* arithmetic, rounding off the result of the division.

Based on your question, you would like to perform floating-point arithmetic.  To do so, at least one of your terms must be specified as (or converted to) floating-point:

Specifying floating point:

```
3.0/2
3.0/2.0
3/2.0
```

Converting to floating point:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
float q = ((float)a)/b;
```

*or*

```
double q = ((double)a)/b;
```

(See [Java Traps: double](https://web.archive.org/web/20120529055141/http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/traps/java_double_traps.html) and [Java Floating-Point Number Intricacies](https://web.archive.org/web/20120215130321/http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/javafloat.htm) for discussions on `float` and `double`)

Answer (score 8):

Check this out: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divideAndRemainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29

You just need to wrap your *int* or *long* variable in a *BigDecimal* object, then invoke the **divideAndRemainder** method on it. The returned array will contain the quotient and the remainder (in that order).

Comment: This is a great answer in that it does answer what the OP is looking for.  One does need to ask though does giving up using a 32 bit primitive for a BigDecimal counteract any savings that one would theoretically get (if the compiler did not perform the optimizations for you)?

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry about it. In your code, just do the separate / and % operations as you mention, even though it might seem like it's inefficient. **Let the JIT compiler worry** about combining these operations to get both quotient and remainder in a single machine instruction (as far as I recall, it generally does).

Answer (score 2):

I mean it's quite simple. Set it as a double. So lets say

```
double answer = 3.0/2.0;
System.out.print(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize both the parameters as `float`, you will sure get actual divided value.
For example:

```
float RoomWidth, TileWidth, NumTiles;
RoomWidth = 142;
TileWidth = 8;
NumTiles = RoomWidth/TileWidth;
```

> Ans:17.75.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;
float c = ((float)a)/b
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by briefly describing what your code does. For example why is it necessary to convert a to a float before the division.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like,

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;
int quotient = a / b;
int remainder = a % b;
```

> To get quotient in real numbers

```
System.out.println((double) a / b);
```

> To get quotient in integer numbers

```
System.out.println("Quotient: " + quotient);
System.out.println("Remainder: " + remainder);
```

> To get quotient in real number such that one number after decimal

```
System.out.println(a / b + "." + a % b * 10 / b);
```

> Note: In the last method it will not round the number up after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

@recursive's solusion (The accepted answer) is 100% right. I am just adding a sample code for your reference.

My case is to display price with two decimal digits.This is part of back-end response: `"price": 2300, "currencySymbol": "CD", ...`.

This is my helper class:

```
public class CurrencyUtils
{
    private static final String[] suffix = { "", "K", "M" };

    public static String getCompactStringForDisplay(final int amount)
    {
        int suffixIndex;
        if (amount >= 1_000_000) {
            suffixIndex = 2;
        } else if (amount >= 1_000) {
            suffixIndex = 1;
        } else {
            suffixIndex = 0;
        }

        int quotient;
        int remainder;
        if (amount >= 1_000_000) {
            quotient = amount / 1_000_000;
            remainder = amount % 1_000_000;
        } else if (amount >= 1_000) {
            quotient = amount / 1_000;
            remainder = amount % 1_000;
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(amount);
        }

        if (remainder == 0) {
            return String.valueOf(quotient) + suffix[suffixIndex];
        }

        // Keep two most significant digits
        if (remainder >= 10_000) {
            remainder /= 10_000;
        } else if (remainder >= 1_000) {
            remainder /= 1_000;
        } else if (remainder >= 100) {
            remainder /= 10;
        }

        return String.valueOf(quotient) + '.' + String.valueOf(remainder) + suffix[suffixIndex];
    }
}
```

This is my test class (based on Junit 4):

```
public class CurrencyUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void getCompactStringForDisplay() throws Exception {
        int[] numbers = {0, 5, 999, 1_000, 5_821, 10_500, 101_800, 2_000_000, 7_800_000, 92_150_000, 123_200_000, 9_999_999};
        String[] expected = {"0", "5", "999", "1K", "5.82K", "10.50K", "101.80K", "2M", "7.80M", "92.15M", "123.20M", "9.99M"};

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int n = numbers[i];
            String formatted = CurrencyUtils.getCompactStringForDisplay(n);
            System.out.println(n + " => " + formatted);

            assertEquals(expected[i], formatted);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Convert your input in double and divide.